# Is there anyway to access the key property from a child in a v-for loop? vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

If possible, I'd like to access the value passed in as key property from a child component in a `v-for` loop. I've added an example of the markup below, in this case `item.value` would be accessible within each `ListItem` component, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<List>
    <ListItem v-for="item in items" :key="item.value">
        {{ item.label }}
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access data from the child, you should be using props (key is reserved so you'll have to name it something else).

Otherwise you can access the key on the vnode within the component via `this.$vnode.key`.

For **Vue 3**: You will need to access the vnode from internal private instance like so: `this.$.vnode.key`. As far as I know this is undocumented and may change; use with caution.

But I would suggest you to go with the `props`!